# Counting Date Backwards in C#

Tags: c#

Can you please show me how to decrement a DateTime by month? For example, today is August 2013, so the count will be July 2013, June 2013, May 2013, April 2013 so on and so forth. And also, the year must also be change when the month reach January going to December. It is like counting the DateTime backwards. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`AddMonths`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addmonths.aspx):

> months: A number of months. The months parameter can be negative or positive.

The usage would look something like:

```
var updatedTime = yourDateTime.AddMonths(-1);
```

Note that calling `AddMonths` returns a *new* instance. Just like with numbers.

Comment: if i used AddMonths(-1) then it reached January, will it automatically also change the year when it goes to december?

Comment: @AmvinCinco why don't you try?

Comment: @AmvinCinco I've added a note to clarify that AddMonths returns a _new_ `DateTime` instead of changing the existing one. My best advice to you is you is to test for yourself :) (yes)

Comment: @I4V Yup, absolutely. And it even says in the documentation (linked by Benjamin in his answer): "The AddMonths method calculates the resulting month _and year_".

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
var monthLater = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1);
```

It will ad `-1` months. You can do this with `Years`, `Days` etc.